# How to setup own remote Monero node with maximum security / anonymity?

Tags: security, full-node

I'm interested in setting up my own remote monero node for personal use on a home computer running OSX. According to [this guide](https://garlicgambit.wordpress.com/2017/01/10/monero-how-to-connect-wallet-to-remote-monero-node-with-ssh/) all I need to do is setup an SSH-connection with a command line which would look somewhat like this:

```
ssh -N -f -L 18081:127.0.0.1:18081 username@ip-remote-monero-node
```

Would it be considered safe to leave my laptop open with monerod running in the background at home on the clearnet and the the Monero GUI with the wallet on a public wifi through Tails? If I'm already outside my home, would it be neccessary to use a VPN over Tails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The major issue here would be that even though you're using Tails, all your connections end up at your home address which itself doesn't hide your IP.

You are correctly hiding your connection to your node but as this one is in your home and only used by you, it will "imply" a connection with yourself. To successfully anonymise the node it should be ran on a remote server which can't be linked to you by at least not "leaking" your private IP to the net.

In this paranoid situation, having a single transaction pushed to the network from a node used by only you and linkable by IP can imply (but not prove) this came from you. With your current setup I would connect from the Tails computer to a public remote node to be fully anonymised.

Comment: Isn't it considered not the safest way to connect to a public remote node? That's why I wish to setup my own node. If I still want to do that, how would I have to set that up so I don't leak my IP / identity as a whole whatsoever ?

Comment: Trusting a remote node implies that you trust it not to manipulate you. A malicious node can record your ip and associate it to a tx-id, tell you the transaction was confirmed while not and other stuff of that kind. The safest way would be to run a VPS in some datacenter which doesn't link it directly to you. Should you have any close friends using Monero, consider sharing a single VPS to "scramble" whose transactions pass through it and, on the fly, to reduce the monthly cost even if you can get a hold on a VPS for less than 5$ a month.